# Bcrypt not that secure at hashing passwords?

Tags: javascript, passwords, cryptography, bcrypt

I am using bcrypt to generate salts and hash passwords, but I do not think that it is doing it very securely.
When I use the following code:

```
bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
  user.salt = salt;
  bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function(err, hash) {
    user.hashed_password = hash;
    console.log(user.salt);
    console.log(user.hashed_password);
    user.save(function(err) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      console.log("saved");
    });
  });
});
```

In one example, the salt is: `$2a$10$mFFjRpY1Vrq7Fy1fFp0fMO` and the hashed_password is: `$2a$10$mFFjRpY1Vrq7Fy1fFp0fMOVnlv9cKgAFdCQ5xdtlP6UoKz90i1FMu`

The beginning of the hashed password is the exact same as the salt. If an attacker has access to the salt, can't he just remove the salt from the hashed_password and either brute force or use a table of predetermined hashed values to determine the password?

I always thought this should be the order of hashing a password:

```
hash(salt + password)
```

Not:

```
salt + hash(password)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The beginning of the hashed password is the salt because you *need* access to the salt in order to verify the password.

The data you see is neither hash (salt + password) nor salt + hash(password) -- it is of the form

```
salt + hash(salt + password)
```

If an attacker gains access to this data, then:

- They can of course (theoretically) brute force the password -- no technique can prevent this, but rate limiting renders the attack impractical. The hash function used in this instance is specifically designed to take a long time to run, indirectly rate limiting the attack.
- They *cannot* use a standard table of hashes to find out the password -- that's because the hashed value also contains the unique salt. Of course the salt is out there in the clear so a table can be calculated, but since the salt is also unique to each hashed password this is no better than a brute force attack.